# jquery accordion (not jquery ui) - links to trigger panels?

Tags: jquery, accordion

We're using this simple little accordion on a page.  It works well enough, but now there's a requirement for a set of links at the top of the page, each of which anchors down to, and opens, a different panel when clicked.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  Please could you help?   For the purposes of the question, you can assume the code in the demo is the code in question.  The only difference is in the structure of the panels, where I've added IDs to the H3 tags to help with the anchors.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/29/nested-accordion/

TIA.

Comment: *"For the purposes of the question, you can assume the code in the demo is the code in question"* but it's not **in the question**... The purpose of that requirement is so that if that demo goes away, your question will still be relevant.

Comment: Yes, fair point.  I was just trying to keep the question succinct.  Noted!

Answer (score 0):

If you have IDs unique to each tag then definitely use those to bind to.
For the fastest (not necessarily the best) way you could do something as simple as using the `data` attribute and something like

`<a class="whatnot" href="#" data-accordionID="ID_HERE">click me</a>`

Then in your script:

```
$(".whatnot").on('click',function(){ 
    var accordionID = "#" + $(this).data("accordionID");
    $(accordionID).click();  //or whatever it is that opens and closes it
});
```

Should work but the only bummer is that it'll be tightly coupled what with the data-id and the actual ID tags.

Comment: Thanks FG - I'll give it a try.  Very kind of you.